# How can I change the function passed params?

Tags: javascript

How can I change the function passed params?

```
function minus_num(num) {
  num -= 1
}

var num_test = 10

while (num > 0){
  minus_num(num_test)
}

console.log(num)  // there I want to get the 0, but it is infinite loop, because the `num` will have a copy in the function.
```

How can I change the `num_test` itself?

Comment: It's good practice not to change argument inside function body. Preferred option is `return num - 1;` as @CertainPerformance anwser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the function to *return* the value after being subtracted, and then you need to assign the result of that to `num_test`.

But `num` is never explicitly declared in your code. You probably wanted to put `num_test` in the loop instead:

```js
function minus_num(num) {
  return num - 1
}

var num_test = 10

while (num_test > 0){
  num_test = minus_num(num_test)
}

console.log(num_test)
```

Answer (score 0):

Primitives are *passed by value*, so you cannot change them in place. Instead you must return the changed value from the function and assign it back to the same variable:

```js
function minus_num(num) {
  num -= 1;
  return num;
}

var num_test = 10

while (num_test > 0) {
  num_test = minus_num(num_test)
}

console.log(num_test);
```

For your current implementation, you will get an error that `num` is not defined because you never declared it before the usage.

Please read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language) to find out more on variable passing to functions.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be

```
function minus_num(num) {
   return num - 1
}

var num_test = 10

while (num_test > 0){
  num_test = minus_num(num_test)
}

console.log(num_test)
```